# How to set up autopay on Xcel Energy?

Tags: website

My friend told me that they got an email from our residential energy utility company Xcel Energy, stating that our account was past due. I thought the account was on auto pay so I hadn't paid it for a couple months.

I logged into the Xcel Energy Residential Account management web application but I can't find the link or button to set up auto-pay.  How do I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I called them and the phone support person said that the auto-pay signup link is hidden (without any indication of this ) if your bill is past due. So you first have to make a manual payment, wait a day or more for it to go through, and then return to the website to set up auto pay.

Once my payment went through, a "Set up Auto Pay" link showed up under "Program Opportunities" on the main landing page for my account.